# Function Apps Vnet/Subnet integration

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, arm, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add VNET integration to my function app, but it does not seem to work.

Is this feature not supported? The release works, but the VNET integration does not.

I have looked at a few examples online and done exactly as presented but no luck. This does however work an a Web App.

Seems strange for something like this to not work.

```
        {
        "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "name": "[parameters('casehandler-function-app-name')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('app-service-plan-name'))]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storage-account-name'))]",
          "microsoft.insights/components/appi-casehandler-pilot"
        ],
          "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('app-service-plan-name'))]",
            "siteConfig": {
              "appSettings": [
          {"name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION","value": "[parameters('FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION')]"},
          {"name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME","value": "[parameters('FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME')]"},
          {"name": "WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE","value": "[parameters('WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE')]"},
          {"name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE","value": "[parameters('WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE')]"},
          {"name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY","value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/appi-casehandler-pilot', '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"},
          {"name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING","value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/appi-casehandler-pilot', '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"},
          {"name": "AzureWebJobsStorage","value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storage-account-name'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storage-account-name')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value,';EndpointSuffix=','core.windows.net')]"}
      ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "config",
            "name": "virtualNetwork",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('casehandler-function-app-name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "subnetResourceId": "[concat(parameters('vnetResourceId'), '/subnets/', parameters('snetName'))]",
                "swiftSupported": true
       }
      }
    ],
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('app-service-plan-name'))]"
        ]
  }
},
```

Comment: check if this helps https://github.com/Hoppy7/ArmTemplates/blob/0b3491c356df1154ac9bb11410f7f8ba3ed6b523/Web/function.vnetIntegrated.json

Comment: It looks more, less same as mine when it comes to the vnet part.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`Microsoft.Web sites/virtualNetworkConnections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-02-01/sites/virtualnetworkconnections?tabs=json)

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
  "kind": "string",
  "properties": {
    "vnetResourceId": "string",
    "certBlob": "string",
    "dnsServers": "string",
    "isSwift": "boolean"
  },
  "resources": []
}
```

Which is missing on your template.

Comment: Can you share your ARM template with this part?

Comment: I switched on networking via azure portal and then exported that template, and even when using that template the subnet is still not being attached.